# Creating a single swagger doc for for multiple python lambdas that are being triggered by ALB

Tags: python, flask, aws-lambda, swagger, swagger-ui

I created five functions in AWS which are being triggered by an ALB.
The lambdas are written in Python and I need to create a single swagger doc for them.
I considered using flask_swagger_ui but the only way I found to make it work is to use a single lambda (instead of five) and let flask do the routing inside that lambda (A solution which is not good for me)
Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Hello - Can you elaborate on your solution more, or show us parts of your current solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an additional Lambda, which is just for documentation purpose.
The functions in that Lambda are just annotated placeholders, and the ALB listener routes only the documentation path requests to this lambda, and the other requests to the "real" Lambdas.